# Post Format Archive template name for theme folder?

Tags: posts, archives, post-formats

What should I call the archive file for a post format? Ex archive-gallery.php? (doesn't work)

I would like to create a list of all the gallery formats with a preview and some custom taxonomies thrown in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well.... for querying, formats are a taxonomy parameter...so that should work....
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Lemme loook...

And yep, here's how that works
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php

Comment: Thanks @Rev. Voodoo ... that should be listed in the [Post Format Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) somewhere.  :)

Comment: Probably a good idea. I guess there isn't really anything there letting you know that a post format is handled as a taxonomy.... The codex is open for anyone to edit (maybe I'll do it, if my writing skills are decent!)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a custom template for the archive index for Post Format types. Your existing template files (`taxonomy.php`, `archive.php`, or `index.php`) will display them just fine.

Just use the following URL structure: `www.example.com/type/{format}/`, which for galleries, would be `www.example.com/type/gallery/`.

[See here for a thorough explanation](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/01/11/using-wordpress-post-formats-as-a-taxonomy/).

Comment: archive-postformat does not work so I assume it should be archive-post-format.php. I'll have to try that. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to create a custom template file, the name would be `taxonomy_post_format-post-format-{type}.php`, which, for Galleries, would be `taxonomy_post_format-post-format-gallery.php`. But, again: I think using such custom template files is overkill.

Comment: Ahh I was had a - where I needed a _ :)